# orderByRaw Not working with jenssegers mongodb Laravel 5

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, jenssegers-mongodb

This the remaining part of my query but whenever i use the below code for ordering by type in the sequel its gives error :

```
exception: the $sort key specification must be an object
```

Query Part :

```
$result =$query->orderByRaw("FIELD('Type', \"UNALLOCATEDPAYMENT\", \"UNALLOCATEDCREDIT\", \"OD\")")->paginate(10);
```

Comment: It seems that orderByRaw is not implemented in Jenssegers's builder, so you need to open an issue on github (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

Comment: i have added the issue https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/820